Azure DevOps: Create release from pipeline with tag (but no branch)
Long story short:

We have a pipeline that compiles and run tests for both our master and dev branches.
It runs as a pre-requisite of every pull-request, because we want to make sure that no broken code is pushed to these branches.
It's the same pipeline because it increases the build number, and one different pipeline for each branch would reset the build no. when we publish to master.
We have a release pipeline that should take artifacts from this pipeline, when a pull-request is completed to master, and publish the app into release.

Our problem: we have been unable to automate this last step. We can't tell the release pipeline to take artifacts from master, because the pipeline runs on the pull-request (and thus, the branch is not master).
We have tagged the pipeline, and we know which pipeline last run for a master pull-request. But, alas, Release pipelines only let us specify a tag for the default branch of the pipeline, or a specific one. But it's a pull-request, so it's a different branch every single time.
Is there any way to get the latest artifact with a specific tag? Are we missing something that we should do to cover our requirements?
Update:
As asked in a comment by Kevin, this is what we tried to do to get the artifacts by branch (it doesn't seem to work because the default branch for the pipeline is dev, not the one that actually run the pipeline):


Can you confirm if you are using the classic Release Pipeline? Can you share the current settings of the release pipeline related to define tag and branch?

Hi Kevin, yes we are using the classic Release Pipeline (we only discovered that they were "classic" after we started using them ). I've just added a screenshot of how we setup the artifacts for the Release pipeline.

Thanks for your update. I think that my previous guess is correct now. The artifacts branch settings have limitations. it can not ignore the branch  and not support wildcards.  To meet your requirement, I have found a workaround to solve the issue. You can check my answer and have a try.

Sorry, I haven’t had the time to try it this week, but this certainly sounds like it should work. As soon as I can test it I’ll confirm the answer! (Thanks!)

Thanks for your update. I will wait for your confirmation

May I know if you had time recently to verify if the answer can work? Feel free to let me know if you have any further questions.


Release pipelines only let us specify a tag for the default branch of the pipeline, or a specific one.

From your description, when we set the branch and tags in the release artifacts, it needs to hardcode the branch name. And  it does not support wildcards.
For example:

Since the branch name of the PR is not fixed, it can not directly meet your requirement.

Is there any way to get the latest artifact with a specific tag? Are we missing something that we should do to cover our requirements?

To meet your requirement, I suggest that you can use the variable to define the branch name in Release Artifacts and save the Pull Request branch name in the variable.
Here are the steps:
Step1: Create Variable Group in Library -> Variable Groups.

Step2: In Build Pipeline, you can add an additional step to update the varible in the Variable Group. Using Azure DevOps CLI:
az pipelines variable-group variable update
For example: you can set the condition for the task to update variable.
- powershell: |
   az devops configure --defaults organization=https://dev.azure.com/orgname project=projectname
   az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id variablegroupid --name branch --value $(Build.SourceBranch)
  displayName: 'Update Variable'
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(system.accesstoken)     
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], "PullRequest"))

Step3: In Release, you can connect the Variable Group to the Release Pipeline.
For example:

Step4: You can use the variable in the Release Artifacts Definition.

In this case, it will automatically fill in the correct Pull Request Branch and select the correct artifacts of the build pipeline.
